# IAM and RBAC Conflicts on Google Cloud Container Engine (GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-iam, kubernetes-security

**Context**

Access to a Google Cloud (GKE) kubernetes cluster is managed through the Google Cloud IAM feature;

1. An admin invites a new user (using their google account/login) and assigns them a role.

   The example role below is "Container Engine Viewer", which will allow the user to access the kubernetes cluster and run all "view" operations.
2. The User can use the `gcloud auth login` on their local machine followed by `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` to authenticate to Google IAM and have the `gcloud` tool write them out a kubernetes config file, ready to use the cluster.
3. Users can then use `kubectl` to access the cluster. With the example above, reads work... writes/changes dont; all good!

**The Problem**

The IAM roles for a GKE kubernetes cluster are very simple, "Admin, Read/Write, Read".

For more fine-grained control over the kubernetes cluster, Kubernetes RBAC
should be used *within* the cluster, allowing me to restrict a user to a single namespace, single API endpoint, single action, etc.

However, without specifying an IAM role for the user; the user has no way of authenticating to the cluster (RBAC is authorization, not authentication).

Yet, the *Lowest* permission IAM role I can set is "Container Engine Viewer", so regardless of the restrictions I implement with Kubernetes RBAC, All my users still have full read access.

**Question**

Has anyone found a way to ensure all permissions in GKE are coming from RBAC, basically nullifying the permissions from IAM?

Answer (score 9):

Weird how writing out the problem gets you to an answer sooner huh?

Theres a new "Alpha" feature in Google Cloud's IAM which wasn't there last time I tried to tackle this problem;

Under IAM > Roles, you can now create custom IAM roles with your own subset of permissions.

I created a minimal role which allows `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` to work, but nothing else, allowing permissions within the kubernetes cluster to be fully managed by RBAC.

Initial testing looks good.

IAM Role Screenshots (with the permissions needed) below.

[Minimal IAM role with GKE cluster access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaUKc.png)

[New IAM roles alpha functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzjsF.png)